# Multiple input text files as stdin under unix

Tags: linux, unix, redirect, piping

new to Linux and C  so probably a simple task..but
As per the title,

How, via the command line, do you redirect 2 distinct files as input, so that when the program is done with the first, it will move on to the second?

```
./a.out < in1.txt   .......
```

Comment: How does this relate to C? Are you asking about shell redirection?

Comment: if you want to send file1, file2... as input for stdin to a program you just have to use `cat` → `cat file1 file2 file3 | ./my_program`. And it has nothing related to C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably what you are looking for is

```
cat in1.txt in2.txt ... | ./a.out
```

which will use `cat` to con**cat**enate the named files to stdout, and the <kbd>|</kbd> (pipe) operator to take the stdout from the left and feed it into the stdin on the right.

```
./a.out > in1.txt
```

redirects *stdout*, not stdin. If you want to redirect stdin, use

```
./a.out < in1.txt
```

But you can only specify one file.

With bash, you can also redirect from the output of a command:

```
./a.out < <(cat in1.txt in2.txt)
```

Comment: that's it. thanks a lot rici. novice question, i know. i appreciate your time and patience.